# Microsoft.Office.Interop

Tags: c#, office-interop

I am using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.dll to create docx file. It works on my local machine, but can you tell me how to use it on server without installing MS-Office or any third party packages?  Please suggest to me some third party tool.

Comment: You cannot use an interop package when there is noting to interop with. Are you looking for an interop replacement package from a third party?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, You have to have MS Office on machine that should run application. Other solution for example via XML:

[Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms406049.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Its much better to use xml access to word documents, especilly on servers. When using iterop services, it creates mess on server - need to install office, then the COM objects are not disposing themselves...

check this: [Open XML SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=5124), use DocumentFormat.OpenXml.dll

Comment: when i used xml then i get this error  "Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {000209FF-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG))." what is the solution of this error